# how to send response to a specific ip address in nodejs or javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with nodejs, and i want to send response from server to a specific ip address but server will be able to listen request from any ip address. Please suggest me how to do this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear and also didn't give any code example of what you have tried. Anyway here is a basic code showing how to get the ipaddress of the client that requested the server and send a response back based in the ip address:

```
var http = require('http');

var s = http.createServer(function(req, res){
     var ipAddress = req.connection.remoteAddress;
     //check if user is accessing from localhost ip
     if(ipAddress=="127.0.0.1"){
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/plain'})
        res.end('Hello localhost');     
     } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/plain'})
        res.end('Hello '+ipAddress);
     }
});
s.listen(8000);
```

Comment: let us suppose you are requesting from 127.0.0.10 , then you will get the response on 127.0.0.10 only, but i want to send response to 127.0.0.20(say) while the request is generated from 127.0.0.10 itself, how can i do this ....

Comment: got it... so i suggest you to read this tutorial http://tech.pro/tutorial/1097/simple-chat-nodejs-plus-websockets